# create array of object of arrays in angular

Tags: arrays, angular

I am trying to get the best possible solution but not getting any clue how to do it.

**Task**

there are 4 different multiple select drop down, and user can select any number of different values of each drop down and create a box ( limit to 7 ) through save button.

**structure**

```
> dropdown1
  a1,a2,a3 

> dropdown2
  b1,b2,b3

> dropdown3
  c1,c2,c3

> dropdown4
  d1,d2,d3
```

**Code for 1 dropdown**

```
  /* dropdown dp1 */
  selecteddp1 = [];
  dp1Loading = false;
  dp1: any[] = [];
  dp1Name = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"];

  selectAll() {
    this.selecteddp1 = this.dp1.map(x => x.name);
  }

  unselectAll() {
    this.selecteddp1 = [];
  }

  private loaddp1() {
    this.dp1Loading = false;
    this.dp1Name.forEach((c, i) => {
      this.dp1.push({ id: i, name: c });
    });
  }
  /* dropdown dp1 */

/* button event */
createQuery() {
    this.selecteddp1.forEach(x => {
      this.query.dp1.push(x);
    });
  }
/* button event */
```

on button event, saving selected dp1 value to query.

```
query:[] = [{
    dp1: [],
    dp2: [],
    dp3: [],
    dp4: []
  }];
```

**result (illustrated based on user selection)**

```
<div class="box1">
  <ul>
    <li>dp1-a1</li>
    <li>dp2-b1</li>
    <li>dp2-b2</li>
    <li>dp3-a1</li>
    <li>dp3-c2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

my approach will be wrong, kindly suggest better idea, how to save the selected value in array of objects and how to view it. TIA

**Edit**
I need to create box with selected value of dropdown(s). Once user click on save button.

In my view,query should be like this

```
query:[] = [{
        dp1: [a1,a2],
        dp2: [b1],
        dp3: [c2],
        dp4: [d3]
      }],
      [{
        dp1: [a1,a2],
        dp2: [b1],
        dp3: [c2],
        dp4: [d3]
      }];
```

Comment: Its not clear what you need exactly.

Comment: @Plochie, hmmmmm.... can you check the edit part of my question.

Comment: can you post your html code? Which framework are you using with Angular?

Comment: @Plochie, framework: angular8

Comment: Your question is how to write the HTML that results in the HTML code you mentioned?

Comment: @Sinandro yes with the values(a1......)

Comment: the query array that you mentioned in the edit section is not a valid code, please update your code to be a valid JS expression.

Comment: @Sinandro, :D I know, that what I am looking for the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your query array like this:

```js
  query = [{
    dp1: ['a1','a2'],
    dp2: ['b1'],
    dp3: ['c2'],
    dp4: ['d3']
  }, {
    dp1: ['a1','a2'],
    dp2: ['b1'],
    dp3: ['c2'],
    dp4: ['d3']
  }];
```

And your HTML whould be:

```html
<div *ngFor="let dropdownGroup of query">
  <select *ngFor="let dropdown of objectKeys(dropdownGroup)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of dropdownGroup[dropdown]" [value]="option">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The `objectKeys` in the HTML is a property of the class that is equal to the `object.keys`:

```js
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

You can see this all together in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwvtzn)